# localtunnel.me fixed url regeneration eveytime server restarts

Tags: node.js, localtunnel

I am using localtunnel.me (https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) to create a connection to my localhost. I am using the following command at the terminal:
lt --port 80 --subdomain test

Everytime I restart the server the url is regenerated to a random server. Is there anyway to get the same url.

Comment: This is a better place to ask: https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might be late to answer but `--local-host xxx.xxx.x.x --subdomain xxxx --port xxx` lets you get the same URL each time. The flags need to be passed in same order.

For example if --subdomain is as follows `--local-host xxx.xxx.x.x --subdomain --port xxx dummy_url` then you will get `https://dummy_url.loca.lt/`

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is correct in a way, though I tried to answer it in a much simpler way since I spent a lot of time debugging issues with getting the same URL for the Local Tunnel.

Suppose, I want my URL should be something like this:

> https://olive-walls-cough-103-181-222-27.loca.lt

You just need to hit the below command:

```
lt --subdomain olive-walls-cough-103-181-222-27 --port 3000
```

Now here the order of flags doesn't matter.

I Have attached the image below with the same thing working!

[image]

Note: Before hitting this command make sure you have installed the `localtunnel` globally.

Refer here for more details: https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/

Comment: This is working for few minutes, after that again start creating dynamic URLs, Is there any permanent way to get only specified URL?